# Not able to create a valid, working, new project while using Vapor4

Tags: swift, vapor, vapor-fluent

My context:

- macOS Catalina version 10.15.3
- Xcode 11.4
- Swift 5.2
- Vapor4

I'm creating a new Vapor project with `vapor-beta new myProjectName`

It asks if I want to use Fluent, which I agree to (y) and asks what kind of database do I want (1. postgreSQL   2. MySql   3. SQLite).
I went with option 3; SQLite is what I need.

It then proceeds to download a template and supposedly customise it with my above selected options.
It stops / freezes at

```
Generating project files
+ Package.Swift
```

Nothing happens after this line, even after 10 minutes of waiting.

When I look in my application folder, there's a hidden .vapor-template folder that seems to contain the folder structure of an app.
I can't simply start using it, because many files seem to be...unfinished, in some way.
For instance, here's how Package.swift looks like:

```
let package = Package(
    name: "{{name}}",
    platforms: [
       .macOS(.v10_15)
    ],
    dependencies: [
        //  A server-side Swift web framework.
        .package(url: "https://github.com/vapor/vapor.git", from: "4.0.0-rc"){{#fluent}},
        .package(url: "https://github.com/vapor/fluent.git", from: "4.0.0-rc"),
        .package(url: "https://github.com/vapor/fluent-{{fluent.db.url}}-driver.git", from: "{{fluent.db.version}}-rc"){{/fluent}}
    ],
    targets: [
        .target(name: "App", dependencies: [{{#fluent}}
            .product(name: "Fluent", package: "fluent"),
            .product(name: "Fluent{{fluent.db.module}}Driver", package: "fluent-{{fluent.db.url}}-driver"),{{/fluent}}
            .product(name: "Vapor", package: "vapor")
        ]),
        .target(name: "Run", dependencies: ["App"]),
        .testTarget(name: "AppTests", dependencies: [
            .target(name: "App"),
            .product(name: "XCTVapor", package: "vapor"),
        ])
    ]
)
```

As you can see, the name of the project is not set (I'm referring to the `name: "{{name}}"` thing), and there are plenty of weird references to `{{#fluent}}` or `"{{fluent.db.version}}-rc")` that freak out the compiler. 
It looks like the "vapor new" command had some more customisation work to do that it simply did not get a chance to finish.
Same story repeats in configure.swift and routes.swift.

I did comb through all of them, deleting the weird placeholders only to bump into some configure.swift situation where it complains about .sqlite not being recognised or something.
I did look it up on google / stackoverflow, tried some fixes that didn't work...until I took a step back an realised that hell...I shouldn't be doing all this SherlokHolmes-ing...the "vapor new" command should simply work and successfully finish...There's plenty of work for me afterwards...This simple, helloWorld-ish step should simply work...

If anyone has some insights into successfully creating a Vapor4 project, I'll be grateful...(simply following the steps at https://docs.vapor.codes/4.0/hello-world/  is not conducive to a working project)

L.E: thanks to imike's suggestion, I headed over to Vapor's community on Discord and found my solution.
My project's folder path happened to contain some spaces and dashes. Removing those allowed the process to finish correctly.
Great, helpful community!

Answer (score 1):

it looks like something is wrong with templating system.

You could fix your  `Package.swift` by yourself

```swift
let package = Package(
    name: "YourProject",
    platforms: [
       .macOS(.v10_15)
    ],
    dependencies: [
        //  A server-side Swift web framework.
        .package(url: "https://github.com/vapor/vapor.git", from: "4.0.0-rc"),
        .package(url: "https://github.com/vapor/fluent.git", from: "4.0.0-rc"),
        .package(url: "https://github.com/vapor/fluent-postgres-driver.git", from: "2.0.0-rc")
    ],
    targets: [
        .target(name: "App", dependencies: [
            .product(name: "Fluent", package: "fluent"),
            .product(name: "FluentPostgresDriver", package: "fluent-postgres-driver"),
            .product(name: "Vapor", package: "vapor")
        ]),
        .target(name: "Run", dependencies: ["App"]),
        .testTarget(name: "AppTests", dependencies: [
            .target(name: "App"),
            .product(name: "XCTVapor", package: "vapor"),
        ])
    ]
)
```

Comment: Thank you for your input, imike.

That's the exact step I took after the initial disappointment; fixing Package.swift along the lines you provided. I ended up with something very similar to what you posted (minus the fluent-postgres-driver, as I had no interest in it; I initially requested sqlite).

However, the problem simply moved to routes.swift.
After fixing that, it moved to configure.swift.

After fixing that as well, it started complaining about something else entirely. Tried to fix it, failed, but even if I were to succeed, I don't know how long this chain would have been.

Comment: Sorry for that bad experience with Vapor :( I'd love to help, write me in Discord to imike#3049 and also we have a great community in Discord https://discordapp.com/invite/vapor where a lot of people are ready to help you with everything